# php regexp to variable

Tags: php, regex, variables, preg-match

How I can write regexp to variable in regular expression?

```
$string = 'Test regular expression';
preg_match('#test (^\s+) expression#is', $string, $b);

//$b[1] = 'regular'; // But I need another way.
```

I want to get

```
$b['string'] = 'regular'; // Not using $b['string'] = $b[1];
```

Maybe

```
$regex = '#test (^\s+)/string/ expression#is';
```

Maybe there's a way to write a regular expression into an array variable in the regular expression?

Thank you, I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with named capturing expressions:

```
preg_match('#test (?P<string>[^\s]+) expression#is', $string, $b);
print_r($b);
```

Comment: Edit: Added missing `[]` round the `^\s`